# iOS Crash at [UIViewController setTitle]

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access, crash-reports

I met a crash with symbolicated result:

```
iOS9.3.1(13E238)
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x000000001500c018
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18181db90 objc_msgSend + 16
1  Foundation                     0x182a8e454 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:] + 324
2  QuartzCore                     0x184c8711c CA::Layer::set_delegate(objc_object*) + 72
3  UIKit                          0x1872f2f40 -[UIView _createLayerWithFrame:] + 580
4  UIKit                          0x1872f2a00 UIViewCommonInitWithFrame + 688
5  UIKit                          0x1872f26f0 -[UIView initWithFrame:] + 140
6  UIKit                          0x1872f9fb0 -[UILabel initWithFrame:] + 48
7  UIKit                          0x187394f04 -[UINavigationItemView initWithNavigationItem:] + 200
8  UIKit                          0x18761de4c -[UINavigationItem _defaultTitleView] + 128
9  UIKit                          0x18761cfbc -[UINavigationItem _addDefaultTitleViewToNavigationBarIfNecessary] + 88
10 UIKit                          0x18739e610 -[UINavigationItem setTitle:] + 260
11 UIKit                          0x187392c90 -[UIViewController setTitle:] + 144
12 XXXXXXXXXXXXX                  0x100107634 -[ZZFileViewController viewDidLoad] (ZZFileViewController.m:133)
13 UIKit                          0x1872f0b40 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 996
14 UIKit                          0x187308fd0 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 132
15 UIKit                          0x1874a3d10 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1052
16 UIKit                          0x1873afd28 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
17 UIKit                          0x1873afa04 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 60
18 UIKit                          0x1873af96c -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 208
19 UIKit                          0x1872ec0e4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 656
20 QuartzCore                     0x184c92a28 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
21 QuartzCore                     0x184c8d634 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 292
22 QuartzCore                     0x184c8d4f4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 32
23 QuartzCore                     0x184c8cb24 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 252
24 QuartzCore                     0x184c8c86c CA::Transaction::commit() + 512
25 UIKit                          0x1872eeef4 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 4980
26 CoreFoundation                 0x18215d124 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
27 CoreFoundation                 0x18215cbb8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
28 CoreFoundation                 0x18215a8b8 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
29 CoreFoundation                 0x182084d10 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
30 GraphicsServices               0x18396c088 GSEventRunModal + 180
31 UIKit                          0x187359f70 UIApplicationMain + 204
32 XXXXXXXXXXXXX                  0x100125c6c main (main.m:14)
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x181c228b8 (Missing)
```

It shows the crash at `[UIViewController setTitle]`, and the title is fetched from a model:

```
- (nonnull NSString *)title
{
    NSString *lastPath = [self.directoryPath lastPathComponent];
    if (0 == [lastPath length]) {
        lastPath = @"/";
    }
    return lastPath;
}
```

From my experience, `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` means sending message to a released object. But here it happens in `viewDidLoad`, could the UIViewController be released? Besides, I don't think the `title` method has memory leak. So I'm confused.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: What's important for you to show us is _when_ you are setting this title. Show the context in which this view controller is created and how its title gets set.

Comment: Update your question with the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: @matt, I simple `setTitle` in viewDidLoad, and the title's value is fetched from a method which is shown above.

Comment: Yes, but maybe there's something odd about the context in which this `viewDidLoad` runs. If you move the `setTitle` to `viewDidAppear` (just as a test) does the crash go away?

Comment: @matt, The crash is from fabric, and I don't find it locally. Sorry to miss that! As it is released, I want to find the root cause, fix and release it.

Comment: Was you able to solve it ?

Comment: @XcodeNOOB, sadly say, NO. I remove the Fabric, and use other tool and no similar bug found.

Comment: @scorpiozj thank you for replying, I have this crash as well, I almost sure it's core data thing and I bet you use core data as your datasource (getting the title from core data). my second thought was that the internal address of the string is change to a different value while settings the title, but I was unable to prove it even when modifying the address on run time. BTW this is not a tool thing, this crash is exist as I encounter it by myself.

Comment: @XcodeNOOB, I didn't use Core Data, and the title was set with pure text.